# Positioning SVGs in IE

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a navigation bar for a website ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PavSidhu/7ze7svqg/1/)) which contains a hamburger menu icon on the left which is an SVG. I have it's position set to `absolute` which works in browsers such as Chrome and Firefox however it does not in IE and Safari for iOS.

So my question is, how should SVGs be positioned so they work in IE as well as other browsers? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your SVG icons a width.

```
.menuIcon {
    position:absolute;
    top:1.75em;
    left:2em;
    width:3em;
    height:3em
}

.searchIconMobile {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    width:2.2em;
    height:2.2em;
    fill:#cfd8dc
}
```